# Wordpress category url

Tags: wordpress, url, categories

I'm having a question about the wordpress url structure. Im building a website that uses categories is a hierachial way. So for example: I have a post with a category, en subcategory and a second subcategory. Lik this

- Main Category
- -First Level Sub
- --Second Level Sub

So its important to show these categories on in the url **and** in the posts. To get the following url stucture i only select the second level sub category in my post. This works oke to get the correct url like this:

```
htt://sitename/main-category/first-level-sub/second-level-sub/postname
```

But then it only shows the second level sub on my post as category and i want it to show: Posted in Main Category | First Level Sub | Second Level Sub

Is there someone who can tell me what is need to do, ore where to look, to accomplish this?

Answer (score -1):

Controlling the permalink structure in Wordpress is easy!
Visit the codex for additional information:

- [Using Permalinks](https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks)

As for your issuse, Go to: **Settings > Permalinks**
and choose a custom structure - enter this:

```
/%category%/%postname%/
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Yes i know that. But the problem is that if you want the url to show all categories (Main / seconda level / Third Level). You have to select only the last (third level) category in your post. But then you will only see the third level in your post also.